# How to have a custom number format that depends on value in a cell

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, mac, vba

So, in cell `A1`, the user may enter **"KG"** or **"LBS"** (data validated).

In cell `A2`, the user enters a number.

And in cell `A3` a calculation is done and displayed using a formula.

I know I can use a custom number format of *0 "KG"* to display **KG** as text next to the number, and *0 "LBS"* to display **LBS**.

Is it possible to have some conditional number format to display **"LBS"** or **"KG"** in `A2` based on the value in `A1`?

I can't use a formula in that cell because the user needs to enter the required data in that cell. In essence, if conditional formatting had a number format section, I could do this pretty simply. I'm on a Mac, so maybe Excel on Windows has this option?

I assume this can be done easily in VBA, but I'm wondering if this can be done without VBA, and how if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you, press ALT + F11 and paste this in,
When ever A1 is changed the number format will change in A2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        With Range("$A$2")
            Select Case Target.Value
Case "KG":
                .NumberFormat = "###""kg"""
Case "LBS":
                .NumberFormat = "###""lbs"""
            End Select
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sean no worries, if it works, accept it as the correct answer for others to see and hopefully use